# What is the jukebox musical?

Tags: vocabulary

What is *jukebox musical* and its origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jukebox Musical is a film musical or stage that uses some recent popular songs as its musical score. The music is mostly got from a well-known group and stars.
Jukebox is a machine in bars, restaurants etc that plays music when you put money in it. That's why we call this Jukebox Musical.

Answer (score 2):

This is a movie genre that rehashes old songs of a certain era. It features music by a particular star or group, e.g., Buddy Holly (The Buddy Holly Story), ABBA (Mamma Mia!), Jersey Boys (Frankie Valli & The Four Seasons), etc.

It originates from the term *jukebox*, which is/was a coin-operated machine that played songs from a list, usually in a diner or bar.